# tightvncserver - Displaying Grey Screen on Kali-Linux upon VNC Connection

Tags: pi-3, ssh, linux, vnc, kali

**PROBLEM**: Upon connecting to my `tightvncerver` on port `5901`, I am greeted with a grey screen with an 'X' for a cursor.

---

**Hardware**: Raspberry Pi 3

**Operating System**: [Kali Linux 0.6 Raspberry Pi 3 w/ Nexmon](https://build.nethunter.com/rpi3-nexmon/)

**Note**: I am using `xfce` as the *display manager* on this machine.

---

**STEPS**:

I start `tightvncserver` using the following command:

`vncserver :1`

Which outputs:

```
New 'X' desktop is kali:1

Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /root/.vnc/kali:1.log
```

Then I attempt to connect to my VNC server as seen below:

[image: VNC Connection Attempt]

**BAM** grey screen! Why?!

---

`/root/.vnc/xstartup`:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

`/root/.vnc/kali:\1.log`:

```
23/01/17 12:46:52 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
23/01/17 12:46:52 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
23/01/17 12:46:52 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
23/01/17 12:46:52 All Rights Reserved.
23/01/17 12:46:52 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
23/01/17 12:46:52 Desktop name 'X' (kali:1)
23/01/17 12:46:52 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
23/01/17 12:46:52 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901

23/01/17 12:59:57 Got connection from client 172.24.1.135
23/01/17 12:59:57 Using protocol version 3.8
23/01/17 13:00:02 Full-control authentication passed by 172.24.1.135
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
23/01/17 13:00:02 Using zlib encoding for client 172.24.1.135
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
23/01/17 13:00:02 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 172.24.1.135
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
23/01/17 13:00:02 Pixel format for client 172.24.1.135:
23/01/17 13:00:02   8 bpp, depth 8
23/01/17 13:00:02   uses a colour map (not true colour).
23/01/17 13:00:02 Using raw encoding for client 172.24.1.135
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
23/01/17 13:00:02 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 172.24.1.135
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
23/01/17 13:00:02 Using hextile encoding for client 172.24.1.135
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
23/01/17 13:00:02 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 172.24.1.135
23/01/17 13:00:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
23/01/17 13:00:02 Pixel format for client 172.24.1.135:
23/01/17 13:00:02   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
23/01/17 13:00:02   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
23/01/17 13:00:02   no translation needed
23/01/17 13:00:08 Client 172.24.1.135 gone
23/01/17 13:00:08 Statistics:
23/01/17 13:00:08   key events received 0, pointer events 158
23/01/17 13:00:08   framebuffer updates 3, rectangles 29, bytes 22762
23/01/17 13:00:08     cursor shape updates 3, bytes 1668
23/01/17 13:00:08     raw rectangles 1, bytes 16396
23/01/17 13:00:08     hextile rectangles 1, bytes 3088
23/01/17 13:00:08     zlib rectangles 24, bytes 1610
23/01/17 13:00:08   raw bytes equivalent 3948580, compression ratio 187.189722
```

Comment: More details regarding this issue-solution on this post: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68046/black-screen-using-vnc-with-raspbian-lite

Comment: Tightvncserver won't work on this version of Kali Linux. Try this. This will help you. https://dephace.com/install-vnc-viewer-on-raspberry-pi-with-kali-linux/ It works fine for me.

Comment: For the record the "What" that that grey screen is: it is an `X` server with nothing on it that has been started with the `-retro` option...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, [Kali Linux 0.6 Raspberry Pi 3 w/ Nexmon](https://build.nethunter.com/rpi3-nexmon/) contains older packages. Once issuing the command `apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade` `tightvncserver` gets replaced by `tigervncserver`. Thus, `TightVNC` isn't part of this image of Kali Linux. `TigerVNC` is a fork that is supported by the standard Kali Linux repositories.

I managed to figure out a pretty good alternative to `TightVNC` and `TigerVNC`. Below is my expanded solution.

### Solution:

I would recommend using `x11vnc` as it provides the actual desktop experience rather than a virtual one.

To install `x11vnc` enter the following command:

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y x11vnc`

If you experience that the `framebuffer` size is too small, then to change it by doing the following:

1. Locate `/boot/config.txt` and open it using `nano` or `vim`

(**Note**: If the file `/boot/config.txt` does not exist, safely power-off the Pi using the command, `poweroff` and take the Micro-SD card out and plug it into a laptop or desktop computer. When the Micro-SD card mounts, open it. The `config.txt` file should be on the root of the mounted Micro-SD card).

2. uncomment the following text in `config.txt`:

*Before*:

`#framebuffer_width=1280`

`#framebuffer_height=720`

*After*:

`framebuffer_width=1280`

`framebuffer_height=720`

3. Save and exit the file. Then, reboot the Pi and start `x11vnc` by using the following command to push it into a background process: `x11vnc -usepw -reopen -bg -forever &`

---

If you would like to start `x11vnc` at boot, add the following to a file called `x11vnc.desktop` in `~/.config/autostart`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=x11vnc
Exec=x11vnc -usepw -reopen -bg -forever &
Comment=Starts an x11vnc server on port kali:5900
```

(**Note**: If `~/.config/autostart` does not exist, create the `autostart` directory by issuing the following command: `mkdir ~/.config/autostart`).

See [how-to-execute-shell-script-on-kali-linux-startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276463/how-to-execute-shell-script-on-kali-linux-startup) for more information on application autostart on Kali Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Doing some additional research, I have come across an additional answer that has solved this problem for me in the past.

---

⚠️ **Please note the below information:**

This solution works [with any of the Raspberry Pi Kali ARM-based images](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/).

That is because these images come with `TightVNC` rather than `TigerVNC` installed.

---

Below is my step-by-step solution:

### **Solution:**

We are going to modify the contents of `~/.vnc/xstartup`, so it will be a good idea to back up its contents first.

`cp ~/.vnc/xstartup ~/.vnc/xstartup.bak`

Now we must modify `~/.vnc/xstartup` to have the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

Now, save and exit the file. Then, reboot the Pi and start `tightvncserver`. The grey screen should be gone and you should be presented with your `xfce4` desktop.