# Black screen using VNC with Raspbian Lite

Tags: vnc, pixel, pi-zero-w, raspbian-lite

I installed the Raspbian lite image to my SD card.

After that I installed PIXEL and VNC Server using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server realvnc-vnc-viewer

sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends raspberrypi-ui-mods gvfs lxterminal xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo
```

But when I connect, I see only black screen.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have discovered a "feature" of the Raspbian Lite OS. The way Raspbian Lite differs from Raspbian is it has no GUI, (Graphical User Interface).

So when you try to VNC into the Pi, you are going to get no GUI, as that is exactly what you would get if you connected the Pi to a monitor using HDMI.

However, I can confirm that using SSH will work normally. Also, if you do want to make use of VNC the normal Raspbian distribution will work and I believe it has VNC built-in and enabled by default.

Edit:

It is possible to install the packages required for a GUI interface, this [page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=133691) on the official Raspberry Pi Forum gives a really good explanation and comparison of the different GUI's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I enable GUI on this? I also installed these packages but still same. https://medium.com/@adrianhdez/installing-raspbian-lite-4e354623311d

Comment: My Raspbian Lite runs connected with a terminal. I can run Kodi just fine. However RealVNC blanks indeed

Comment: I had SSH working, but you need more than just the desktops offered in the link at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=133691 - I also needed DISPMANX: http://raspmer.blogspot.ca/2015/07/vnc-server-for-raspberry-pi-with.html - See my answer on this post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I read tons of posts about this issue... and they all resulted in a RealVNC / x11VNC / Remoter black screen VNC connection on my Mac to my Raspberry Pi.

DISPMANX was the ulimate solution to VNC into the Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Lite.

Here is the summary:

1) BASIC SETUP - RESULTS IN BLACK SCREEN FOR VNC

SSH Enabled via Raspi-Config on Raspberry Pi
Remoter for Mac (VNC + SSH/Terminal Access)
SETUP: https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/take-control-of-your-raspberry-pi-using-your-mac-pc-ipad-or-phone--mac-54603

2) TO ELIMINATE BLACK SCREEN FOR VNC

Setup DISPMANX, Desktop GUI for Raspbian Lite needs Additional Support
SETUP: http://raspmer.blogspot.ca/2015/07/vnc-server-for-raspberry-pi-with.html

3) START DISPMANX VNC VIA RASPBERRY PI DESKTOP/GUI - NOT REMOTE SSH/TERMINAL
sudo dispmanx_vncserver

4) CONNECT VIA REMOTER TO IP

MORE: [Black screen using VNC with Raspbian Lite](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68046/black-screen-using-vnc-with-raspbian-lite)

[image: SUCCESS]

Answer (score 0):

If it's not actually Raspbian Lite then the problem could be that on the VNC SERVER you need to go in Options -> Expert -> CaptureMethod = 1

See [Black or blank screen when connecting to VNC Server running on Windows 10](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004012211-Black-or-blank-screen-when-connecting-to-VNC-Server-running-on-Windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

With Raspberry OS Lite use SSH+Screen.
On Lite:

`screen -d -m -S 1`

-S 1 is the name. Without -dm will exit when closing from remote.

`screen -x 1`

On remote ssh in then same:

`screen -x 1`

*Ctrl+a+d* on remote to detach.